# Does anybody else skim the protein off the top of their boil?

Tags: boil, boilover

I've been doing it lately, assuming it will reduce the amount of crap I have to filter out after the boil, and it seems to reduce the amount of head I get during the boil (less chance of a boil over).

Does anybody else do this or does anybody have any insight as to whether or not I should be doing it and why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't.   Mostly because I'm lazy, but I think it also serves as some extra nutrients for the yeast.

Comment: Could you elaborate on what nutrients it provides?

Comment: I don't actually know.   It may be something I heard, or something that I misheard and filled in the blanks with bad info.   I was just listening to some Brew Strong archives a couple of hours ago, and in the Head Retention episode,  McDole mentioned that he got better head retention when he didn't skim.   I may have just projected from that.

Comment: I'd guess that's due to not removing proteins from the beer by skimming rather than "yeast nutrition".

Comment: http://www.byo.com/stories/techniques/article/indices/13-boiling/1682-wort-boiling-homebrew-science

"... cold break contains some unsaturated fatty acids required for yeast nutrition"

Does hot break contain any of those things?

Answer (score 6):

I tried doing it for a couple years.  I found it made no difference whatsoever to the beer quality so now I don't bother.  The only valid reason I've heard for doing it is to help prevent boilovers on small kettles, but I find Fermcap far more effective for that.

Comment: That's right point - i have 29L kettle and 27L of wort easily boils off if i don't remove them before hop addition.

Answer (score 1):

Palmer recommends throwing a couple of copper pennies into the pot to prevent boilover.

http://www.howtobrew.com/section1/chapter1-1.html